# chlorination of aromatic compounds

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution

I was reading some notes on **Electrophilic Substitution** and I came across the topic chlorination of **Toluene**. I'm wondering why we cannot substitute chlorine in the meta position of toluene?

Answer (score 3):

We do get meta-chlorotoluene when toluene is chlorinated by EAS, but only in minor amounts.  [This paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4344/8/11/532/htm) describes a process designed to selectively produce the ortho isomer over the para one, but in addition to some para-chlorotoluene still being formed the abstract reports 4.0% meta-chlorotoluene.  There are also small amounts of dichlorinated products and even benzyl chloride.

[This Youtube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=te88q7q6zhk) describes a synthesis route from benzene that favors meta-chlorotoluene.

- Nitrate the benzene.
- Apply Friedel-Crafts methylation which gives substitution meta to the nitro group.  The remaining steps ultimately exchange the nitro group for a chlorine atom.
- Reduce the nitro group to amino using tin plus acid.
- Convert the amino group to a diazonium ion with nitrite plus acid.
- React the diazonium ion with cuprous chloride plus HCl.

Meta-chlorotoluene is available at 98% purity from Sigma-Aldrich.